# UML class diagram shows an interface using a class, but should it show concrete classes using the same class

Tags: uml, software-design

Please see the diagram below for this question...

I am trying to make a UML class diagram of an interface (IView) that has a method (abstract) that takes as a parameter a reference to a class (Card) in another package. I found a stackoverflow post that suggested that in UML, this should be expressed as "IView 'uses' Card" (Apologies, but I do not have the reference and I cannot re-locate it currently).

IView is implemented by two classes, and each of those concrete classes "uses" Card (of course). In the diagram, do I also need to express the "uses" relationship between the concrete classes and Card (not shown below)?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a too bad attempt. The top dependency is almost correct. You *named* the dependency `Use` but that's futile. You can just leave away that name. You *could*  make it a use-dependency by adding the *key word* `«use»` but that's not needed. Just leave it a simple dependency.

Similarly the lower dependencies where the name `Implements` is futile. Anyhow, these should be realize relations. Use a closed triangle instead of the open arrow. And it's not necessary to name it either.

Finally you should just drag the attribute `field` into `iView` since it seems that this is a common attribute for the views (here I'm just guessing).

**tl;dr**

There is no need to draw a dependency from from the classes at the bottom to the top one.